# How to get the array of all ngrams in Perl Text::Ngrams

Tags: perl, n-gram

As you know the module [Text::Ngrams](http://search.cpan.org/~vlado/Text-Ngrams-2.003/Ngrams.pm) in Perl can give Ngrams analysis. There is the following function to retrieve the array of Ngrams and frequencies.

```
get_ngrams(orderby=>'ngram|frequency|none',onlyfirst=>NUMBER,out=>filename|handle,normalize=>1)
```

But it gives only the last Ngrams. 
For example the following code does not give both Uni-Gram and Bi-Gram:

```
my $ng3 = Text::Ngrams->new( windowsize => 2, type=>'byte');
my $text = "test teXT TESTtexT";

$text =~ s/ +/ /g; # replace multiple spaces to single
$text = uc $text; # uppercase all

$ng3->process_text($text);
my @ngramsarray = $ng3->get_ngrams(orderby=>'frequency', onlyfirst=>10, normalize=>0 );
foreach(@ngramsarray)
{
    print "$_\n";
}
```

output:

```
T E
4
E X
2
_ T
2
E S
2
S T
2
X T
2
T _
2
T T
1
```

However by using the function

```
to_string(orderby=>'ngram|frequency|none',onlyfirst=>NUMBER,out=>filename|handle,normalize=>1,spartan=>1)
```

it shows both of Ngrams. But only it displays the result. I need the result in an array.

How to get all Ngrams (Unigram and Bigram) at the same time by this array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get all the different sizes of n-grams at the *same time*, but you can get them all using multiple calls to `get_ngrams`. There is an undocumented parameter `n` to `get_ngrams` that says the size of the n-grams you want listed.

In your code, if you say

```
my @ngramsarray = $ng3->get_ngrams(
  n => 1,
  orderby = >'frequency',
  onlyfirst => 10,
  normalize => 0);
```

you get this list

```
('T', 8, 'E', 4, 'X', 2, '_', 2, 'S', 2)
```